# Drop table with cascade constraint

Tags: liquibase

How do I configure Liquidbase to add cascadeConstraints=true to my diff file when I execute liquibase diffChangeLog? There are drop table commands, but they fail due to other tables having FK on them.

Answer (score 1):

When Liquibase does a diffChangeLog, it tries to do the best that it can, but in your case it won't be able to do what you want. I think your best course of action would be to add the cascadeConstraints attributes manually.